# Can I keep a query synchronized (KeepSynced)?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

In an Inventory App (IOS & Android), inside the path /outputs I am saving the records of each Output. Over time this base gets bigger and bigger (thousands of records), however the most common query is related to the outputs of the last two days (usually 20 or 30 records).

Even though I use a filter to make the query (`db.child('PATH/outputs').orderByChild('date').startAt(yesterdayDate).endAt(todayDate)`), I feel that it is taking more and more time (maybe minutes) to get the result of the last two days, so I have thought about the possibility of handling a keepsynced.

Currently within the Firebase rules I indicated that `date` is one of the important children ...

```
   "outputs": {
     ".indexOn": ["date", "name"],
   }
```

I tried to do the following but it didn't work for me (`Failed Assertion Error`):

```
   db.child('PATH/outputs').orderByChild('date')
    .startAt(yesterdayDate).endAt(todayDate)
    .keepSynced(true);
```

Is there a way to `keepsynced` only a part of the node and not the whole node?

**How can I optimize the time of a typical query such as bringing the results of the day?**

Comment: "I feel that it is taking more and more time to get the result of the last two days" If the result set isn't growing, it should not be taking significantly more time. Do you have some data about data size and time taken to go with that feeling?

Comment: It should be possible to keep a query synchronized. Is there any additional information in the assertion error you get?

Comment: It's the error `'package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart': Failed assertion: line 97 pos 12: 'value is String ||
package:firebase_database_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:1
        value is bool ||
        value is double ||
        value is int ||
        value == null': is not true.`

Comment: Hmm... I don't see what you might be doing wrong there. Is this iOS, Android or Web? The latter definitely won't work, as offline persistence is only implemented for native mobile SDKs - but I'd expect a different error message for that. --- Also, did you see my first comment? Any update on that?

Comment: Regarding the time and size, the total size of the node is around 3.1MB. The very first query takes a variable time (20 secs - 1 minute). It takes time even when the query returns 0 results.

Comment: Very first query = It is the first query (before caching any information)

Comment: I'm doing tests in IOS and Android

Comment: Hmm... I'm wondering if you're downloading the entire JSON, despite using a query. Are you sure the index is defined on the correct level in the rules?

Comment: 3.1MB is the total size of the node (I export it in my Firebase Console). It's not the size of the query

Comment: Regarding the index level, mmm... I'm using the rule that you can see in the Question. Maybe, do I need to use the id level? Something like...             `"outputs": {"$outputs_id": {".indexOn": ["date", "name"]`